# Automated testing of FLEX based applications

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, testing, web-applications

What tools, preferably open source, are recommended for driving an automated test suite on a FLEX based web application? The same tool also having built in capabilities to drive Web Services would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

Adobe distributes a test framework themselves: [FlexUnit](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexunit/FlexUnit).

Comment: I would suggest FlexUnit for automated testing of libraries you're building but it is a serious pain to use for a full application.

Answer (score 2):

I heard of people using selenium as a free/open source testing tool. A quick google revealed a FLEX API for it. Not sure if it works or is still in development, but it may be worth a look.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/seleniumflexapi/

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to script code-level unit tests? If so, dpuint is the bomb: http://code.google.com/p/dpuint/ . This library makes it really easy to do automated testing on all sorts of asynchronous events, on either non-visual ActionScript objects or visual components. They also have a nice multi-page tutorial on the Google Code project page.

If you are looking for functional testing tools along the lines of automated record-and-playback simulating an end user using a Flex app, HP's QuickTest Pro is the Adobe-endorsed solution. It works great, but costs about $4,000 - $6,000 per seat.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [FlexMonkey](http://code.google.com/p/flexmonkey/).  It does automated testing via FlexUnit tests.

Comment: FlexMonkey may be more of a pain than it is worth. Gorrilla Logic claims it works with custom components but I have found this is not the case. Anything with a renderer seems to have serious problems. It is a lot harder to set up tests than they claim and the tests aren't stable. I have written tests for one component 5 times now using hardcoded ids. Sometimes it just can't see the component and it dies. They only have 3 short paragraphs explaining tests in their user guide and they only respond to questions about how to set it up on their google group. I would avoid using this.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at Melomel. It has Cucumber support baked right in and comes packaged with steps for most Halo and Spark components.

http://melomel.info

Comment: This appears to be a dead link now.

Answer (score 1):

There's an automated test tool called [RIATest](http://www.riatest.com/) that might fit the bill for you.

Unfortunately only for Windows, and not open source, but if it does the job it might be well worth the price ($399 at time of writing).

Answer (score 1):

[FunFX](http://funfx.rubyforge.org/) is an option for automating UI testing.  I haven't used it extensively, but I've heard of some having success with it.  [Here](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2008/06/22/observations-on-test-driving-user-interfaces) is the article where I first learned about it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been extensively using [FunFX](http://github.com/peternic/funfx) for several months now on a Flex 3 + Rails project. Not only is it open source, it's also written in Ruby, so integration with web services should be fairly easy. There are a few [screen](http://onrails.org/articles/2009/07/08/screencast-testing-flex-apps-with-cucumber)[casts](http://onrails.org/articles/2009/07/13/screencast-testing-flex-apps-with-cucumber-take-2) out there covering the basics.

Answer (score 1):

The Flex code that your Flex app needs is contained in the SeleniumFlexAPI distribution .swc file, SeleniumFlexAPI.swc. Just include this file as a library when you compile your Flex app.

Answer (score 1):

Sikuli is good tool which can be used to test flex/flash based web applications.
-It can automate anything on graphical user interface.
-It works on Windows, MAC OSX and Linux as well as iPhone and Android.
-Here is the [Sikuli link](http://www.sikuli.org/)

Answer (score 0):

My preferred tool is Selenium Remote Control.  There is a plug-in I discovered a few months ago:

http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/

This required 'hooks' to be written on the server side (ActionScript/Flex).  Once they were added, I was able to do some browser testing using Selenium RC.

Answer (score 0):

FunFX is great. We've used it extensively and have been very happy with it. The community is also active and very responsive, so that is a big plus for me.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the [Selenium-Flex API (0.2.5)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/seleniumflexapi/) works great.