# Flex UI testing automation

Tags: apache-flex, testing, user-interface, automation

We have a flex based UI whose functionality (eg: login, logout) needs to be tested periodically in IE 7. Manual testing takes a lot of time and hence we want to automate it.

EDIT: We dont have the source code of this app uder test so cannot use something like FlexUnit. Is there a way to automate this testing?

I have heard of FleXmonkey, but have read negative reviews of it and hence wary of trying it.

EDIT: source of negative review:
[Automated testing of FLEX based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462/automated-testing-of-flex-based-applications)
(Comment by Ryan H)

Please suggest if theres a way to go about it.

**EDIT:** An open-source solution is preferred.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello Pratyusha! I know this is a very old question, but did Saucelabs IDE help test flex? I am trying with flex but it's not recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without recompiling the source code, it is not possible to test Flex in all cases. Saucelabs IDE claims that it can test Flex without recompiling the code. You may check that.

Comment: SauceLabs seems useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get very far in your development adventures if you avoid reviewing things just because you read negative reviews.  ( Please provide a source for said negative reviews ).  I've also read bad things about Flex and Flash Builder and the Flash Player.  Yet, you still ended up using Flex?

That said, I strongly suggest checking out [Flex Monkey](http://flexmonkey.gorillalogic.com/).

[RIATest](http://www.riatest.com/) is another option.

I believe you can also do this sort of testing with [QTP](http://qtpfaq.blogspot.com/2007/07/interview-question-10-how-to-automate.html).  I couldn't find a specific source for QTP info, but there are a few links if you google.

http://www.learnqtp.com/does-quicktest-professional-support-flashadobe-flex-applications/
http://vishnuagrawal.blogspot.com/2009/04/flex-automation-testing-with-qtp.html

Comment: Looks like we need the source code to get Flex Monkey working and all I have is a URL to acess the app. Thanks.

Comment: You do not need the FlexMonkey source to use it.

Comment: @James Ward Actually, it depends what you're doing.  If you're doing crazy stuff w/ custom components, you'll need to write your own automation delegates for said components and compile those into FlexMonkey somehow.  I was never able to get it to work for the Flextras Calendar, and eventually gave up.  My memory is a bit hazy on actual issues.

Comment: @Pratyusha You can get full access to the source for Flex Monkey. You'll need to check out of SVN yourself, though.  Instructions should be on the FlexMonkey web site somewhere.

Comment: www.Flextras.com: I meant source code of the app I need to test.

Comment: If I understand, you're trying to create UI tests for an app where all you have is the compiled SWF?  Why?  What is your use case?  Are you building a spider?

Answer (score 0):

I think FlexMonkey is pretty cool and worth judging on your own.  Most of these tools use the same underlying automation framework provided by Adobe, and thus have many of the same pains and challenges.  We've actually done a lot the last few months to make it easier to work with and have been working to provide more documentation on dealing with common challenges.

If you do have problem, you will find that our Forums are very active with questions and answers: http://www.gorillalogic.com/forum/7

-Jon Rose - 
Gorilla Logic, Inc

Comment: Thank you Jon. I understand you'd need access to source code of the app being tested, to use FlexMonkey and we don't have that. I will check it out, I can probably use it in another scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Some Flex automation tools support testing of Flex applications without requiring to recompile it.

[RIATest](http://www.riatest.com/) definitely supports it (called runtime loading) and if I am not wrong [QTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional) does it as well. AFAIK there are no open source tools that support it.

Beware though that runtime loading is not for every application. If for example you are using custom html wrapper you cannot use it with runtime loading.