# Flex Web App automated testing

Tags: apache-flex, testing, selenium, automated-tests

I want to test my web App developed on Flex 3.

I have used `selenium`, but working with it is a pain since it has problem deceting some custom components. It has problems working with pop up window, etc.

Can you suggest to me a new tool to work with?

Comment: Are you looking to spend lots of money or get it for free? (or somewhere in between)?

Comment: Other than QTP mentioned in an answer; you can also look for "Flex Monkey" which was renamed but I forget what the new name is.  And RIATest which is a commercial tool for this.  There is also unit test tools such as FlexUnit.  This question most likely got closed b/c it is not a specific programming question; and many would say "StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine"

Answer (score 2):

In my former company, we used Mercury QTP (part of the Mercury Test Director suite, now a property of HP). It was working fine with Flex 1.5, 2 and 3 as long as you put ids on all your application components, widgets ... and that you embed some SWC files while compiling (automation.swc mainly).

But I assume you're looking for a "free" test utility. You should have a look here:
[Automated testing of FLEX based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462/automated-testing-of-flex-based-applications)

There are some UI testing software listed.

Comment: Note that Test Director is a "whole enchilada" tool; you really mean QTP (QuickTest Pro).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant QTP